# Boxplot from dictionary with different length

Tags: python

I have one dictionary with different length of the values for each key. Trying to plot as a `boxplot`, I cant go forward. is there any other method to do this?

I wrote this but it doesn't work:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import matplotlib as mpl 

dict1 = {'Pb': [53.0, 56.0, 56.0, 57.0, 57.0, 57.0, 46.0], 'Pa': [56.0, 55.0], 'Pg': [57.0, 57.0, 58.0, 57.0, 57.0, 57.0, 57.0, 57.0,53.0, 57.0, 55.0, 58.0, 58.0, 58.0, 57.0, 57.0, 57.0, 57.0, 57.0, 55.0, 55.0, 57.0, 57.0, 55.0, 58.0, 58.0, 58.0, 55.0, 58.0, 54.0, 58.0, 57.0, 57.0, 58.0, 55.0, 56.0, 55.0, 55.0, 55.0, 58.0, 56.0, 57.0, 57.0, 57.0, 57.0, 56.0, 57.0, 56.0],'Pf': [54.0], 'Pn': [56.0, 56.0, 55.0, 56.0, 56.0, 56.0], 'Ps': [58.0, 56.0, 57.0, 56.0, 56.0, 55.0, 56.0, 56.0, 56.0, 55.0, 56.0, 56.0, 56.0, 58.0, 57.0, 58.0, 57.0, 57.0, 56.0, 58.0, 56.0, 53.0, 56.0, 56.0, 56.0, 56.0, 56.0, 56.0]}

      # remove from here
for k, v in dict1.iteritems():
      boxplot(k,v) 
      plt.show()
```

The solution proposed and tested: Just substitute the interpretation to the text below. It works with **python 3.5**

```
#And include this:
labels, data = [*zip(*dict1.items())]  # 'transpose' items to parallel key, value lists
    plt.boxplot(data)
    plt.xticks(range(1, len(labels) + 1), labels)
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

did you want all the values together?
`[n for v in dict1.values() for n in v]` 'flattens' the list of values

then a boxplot is a matplotlib standard plot https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/boxplot_demo.html

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


plt.boxplot([n for v in dict1.values() for n in v])
```

[image]

or by key

```
# Python 3.5+
labels, data = [*zip(*dict1.items())]  # 'transpose' items to parallel key, value lists

# or backwards compatable    
labels, data = dict1.keys(), dict1.values()

plt.boxplot(data)
plt.xticks(range(1, len(labels) + 1), labels)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: By keys. The problem was that I couldn't use panda and did not find the best solution; Great!

Comment: 'labels, data = [*zip(*dict1.items())]  # 'transpose' items to parallel key, value lists
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax'
It is appearing this after processing. Do you have any idea?

Comment: restarted Spyder, cut&pasted from my answer, works fine, Python 3.6.3  Probably Python version changes to either or both `unpacking` and `dict.items()` https://www.google.com/search?q=python+version+dict.items()+changes&oq=python+version+dict.items()+changes&aqs

Comment: `labels, data = dict1.keys(), dict1.values()` seems to work for collecting the lists in a online 2.7 interpreter - didn't check the grapics